# Passing String::as_str to Option<String>::map() fails to compile with a type mismatch error

Tags: rust

The second `map` statement in this code fails to compile.

```
fn main() {
    let hello = Some("hello");
    let _switcheroo = hello.map(str::to_string); //ok

    let hello = Some("hello".to_string());
    let _switcheroo = hello.map(String::as_str); //not ok
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
 --> src/main.rs:6:29
  |
6 |     let _switcheroo = hello.map(String::as_str); //not ok
  |                             ^^^
  |                             |
  |                             expected signature of `fn(std::string::String) -> _`
  |                             found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r std::string::String) -> _`
```

I would expect an error about borrowing some moved data. What is this error trying to say?

This does compile:

```
let hello = Some("hello".to_string());
let _switcheroo = hello.as_ref().map(String::as_str); //ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `String::as_str` expects a reference to a `String` rather than the `String` itself. `String::as_str`'s signature is `fn as_str(&self) -> &str`, so you can see that it takes `self` (the `String`) as a reference.

To interpret the error message, look at the "expected" vs "found". In the "expected" part of the message, we see `fn(std::string::String) -> _`, so it's expecting a function that takes `std::string::String` (i.e. `String`) and returns some irrelevant type (`_`). In the "found" part of the message however, we find `for<'r> fn(&'r std::string::String) -> _`. This is harder to understand since it uses an idea that's rarely seen in Rust code.

The `for<'r>` part means that the function should be generic with respect to the lifetime. It should accept any lifetime and a `String` with that lifetime. The output type can also have the given lifetime. Usually a function like this has a signature like `fn foo(x: &T) -> &U` and the lifetimes are implicitly added. This is exactly what `String::as_str` is.

One way to fix your code is to ensure that a reference is passed to `map`. Something like `let _switcheroo = hello.as_ref().map(String::as_str);` should work.